# Trying to understand SharePoint Enterprise CAL

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, cal

I am a SharePoint developer for few years, but this is my project where I need to install SP2013. Before installing, I am trying to understand the SP licenses. Currently I have SharePoint Server 2013 with Standard CAL(I got this from Central Admin). But I will also need to activate **InfoPath Forms Services**, but I don't have Enterprise Product Key. I also have InfoPath already installed on my laptop. So my question is, what are the licenses/CALs that I need to buy? Enterprise Server license and one CAL per developer per environment? 
Your replies will be very helpful to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

InfoPath is an enterprise SKU feature.  As such you need

- SharePoint 2013 Enterprise Server License
- SharePoint 2013 Standard CAL
- SharePoint 2013 Enterprise CAL (this doesn't include standard, they are separate, so you need both).

Client Access Licenses are per user.  If you have 5 active developers you need 5 standard and enterprise CALS.

And of course you need an office package that includes InfoPath client (which you already have).

There are some other options as well.  If you have an MSDN subscription you are probably covered. You can also leverage the trial downloads which are good for 120 days.

On a related note.  You may or may not be aware but Microsoft has announced they are no longer actively developing InfoPath and will be developing alternatives.  Most of these are showing up for O365, but regardless I have been recommending people explore other options for their forms (there are a host of other reasons to avoid InfoPath as well).